# No values written to csv file from txt file

Tags: python, csv

"""Trying to learn about text file editing in python. Been following along with this socratica video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xi52tx6phRU&t=) in an attempt to do so. When trying to run the same code I am given a value error that tells me that unconverted data remains. While I could do without the error code, this makes sense as it is the day one google stock price data that has no previous day to compare to. I am more so concerned with how I open the google file the coding creates and nothing is there. I would appreciate what guidance I can get as I get, let me know if I am missing any information or if further clarification is required. Coding is below, other than the file directory I believe it to be the same as what was gone over in the video."""

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
path = 'C:/Users/ejose/Documents/Python Scripts/Things That Losers Wont Do/Matthes/Files and Exceptions/text_files/google_stock_data.txt'
file = open(path, newline='')
reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader) #The first line is the header

data = []
for row in reader:
    # row = [Date, Open, High, Lower, Close, Volume, Adj. Close]
    date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y')
    open_price = float(row[1])
    high = float(row[2])
    low = float(row[3])
    close = float(row[4])
    volume = int(row[5])
    adj_close = float(row[6])

    data.append([date, open_price, high, low, close, volume,
                 adj_close])

# Compute and store daily stock returns

returns_path = 'C:/Users/ejose/Documents/Python Scripts/Things That Losers Wont Do/Matthes/Files and Exceptions/text_files/google_returns.csv'
file = open(returns_path, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(File)
writer.writerow(['Date','Return'])

for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    today_row = data[i]
    todays_date = todays_row[0]
    todays_price = todays_row[-1]
    yesterdays_row = data[i+1]
    yesterdays_price = yesterdays_row[-1]

    daily_return = (todays_price - yesterdays_price) / yesterdays_price
    formatted_date = todays_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    writer.writerow([formatted_date, daily_return])
```

The traceback information is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ejose\Documents\Python Scripts\Things That Losers Wont Do\Matthes\Files and Exceptions\google_stock_values.py", line 13, in <module>
    date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y')
  File "C:\Users\ejose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\ejose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains:   585.002622  587.342658  584.002627  586.862643  978600  586.862643
```

Comment: Post the stack trace so we can see which line has the problem.

Comment: `strptime` raises that error if extra data remains in the string being parsed. Try `print(row)` before your date conversion to see what is in `row[0]`. You may have to trim up that string before applying the time conversion.

Comment: Just added the traceback generated, I trust that is what you are referring to when you say stack trace.

I print the row before the date conversion, I get the values tab separated, not what I see in the youtube lesson. Not clear on why strip doesn't remove the tabs either for that matter.

Comment: That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with some frustrating limitations of the tools. First `strptime` expects that the string you feed it holds exactly the date expressed in the format string. The value error shows that a bunch of stuff remains

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:   585.002622  587.342658  584.002627  586.862643
```

It looks like the csv reader didn't break the line into cells. `csv.reader`
defaults to a comma delimiter but yours is using something else. It appears to me that it is using 2 spaces although its possible that its really a tab that was lost on copy/paste into this question.

If its a tab, you can just change the reader:

```
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")
```

If its two spaces, there is more work to do. `csv.reader` only accepts a 1 character delimiter. Since your csv looks simple, you can fix the spaces as you iterate lines

```
reader = csv.reader(line.repace("  ", " ") for line in file)
    delimiter=" ")
```